# Kernel do_gettimeofday going to past

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel

Using Kernel 3.9, the `do_gettimeofday` seems to be going into the past, for instance:

```
do_gettimeofday(&t);
time_to_tm(t.tv_sec, 0, &broken);
printk("One: %d:%d:%d:%ld\n", broken.tm_hour, broken.tm_min, broken.tm_sec, t.tv_usec);

(...) some processing

do_gettimeofday(&t);
time_to_tm(t.tv_sec, 0, &broken);
printk("Two: %d:%d:%d:%ld\n", broken.tm_hour, broken.tm_min, broken.tm_sec, t.tv_usec);
```

It shows:

```
[  140.754752] One: 0:2:15:761239
[  140.755139] Two: 0:2:8:539096
```

How is this possible ?

Comment: What if you don't convert time and print timeval structure seconds and microseconds?

Comment: The same problem occurs.